# How to fix error with boost memory mapping in visual studio that causes ios_base::failure from boost::wraexcept

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to learn about implementation of memory mapped files using the boost libraries. I have tried using many example codes and even the simplest implementations such as reading a file causes errors. I keep receiving the same error message about Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept at memory location. Has any solved this issue using visual studio on windows?

I have tried to debug the code of some of the examples I have used but I still don't understand how to fix the problem.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp> // for mmap
#include <algorithm>  // for std::find
#include <iostream>   // for std::cout
#include <cstring>
int main()
{//have use memory mapped file in read only mode and read the stduff.txt file
boost::iostreams::mapped_file mmap("stduff.txt", boost::iostreams::mapped_file::readonly);
    auto f = mmap.const_data();
    auto l = f + mmap.size();

    uintmax_t m_numLines = 0;

//read out the data in the file and number of line
    while (f && f != l)

        if ((f = static_cast<const char*>(memchr(f, '\n', l - f))))
            m_numLines++, f++;

    std::cout << "m_numLines = " << m_numLines << "\n";
}
```

I expect the coded to read  m_numlines = 1, but I get a Microsoft c++ exception thrown instead.

Comment: Start from an answer on the question: is the file with the given name accessible from the program working directory? Use the full path if you're not sure.

Comment: I have made sure the file is in the working directory and I have used the full path but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: was able to fix it you were right about checking the directory.